# jQuery Drop Down Menu doesn't work in IE7

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

I have a jQuery drop down menu on one of my company's sites. The menu works in every browser except IE7. I have tried modifying the jQuery and the CSS. I've tried implementing every fix I've seen listed on this site and any other fix a quick google search provides. So far nothing has helped. The worst part is I'm not sure what part isn't working.

I've heard that certain versions of IE don't support the :hover class. I tried creating a variable for the .hover function. Someone else posted that IE7 doesn't like display:block so I tried altering that. Nothing is working.

This is my code minus the CSS. The site is:  http://www.triconference.com

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#nav li').hover(function () {

                                    //show its submenu
                                    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(300);

                                },

                                function () {
                                    //hide its submenu
                                    $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
                               }
               );

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using .mouseover or .mouseenter instead of .hover
http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work either. Thank you though.